# Create loops with perl regex patterns

Tags: regex, perl, loops, fsm

Is it possible to create loops in perl regex patterns like so:

```
(?<A>^|(?&B)a)(?<B>(?&A)b)
```

Regex101 is not accepting it. I undertand that I could just write:

```
(ba)?
```

but I would like to understand if I would be able to create patterns and then use them (I'm trying to easily convert a quite complex FSM into a regex without losing sanity).

Comment: You could change it to `(?<A>^|(?=.)(?&B)a)(?<B>(?=.)(?&A)b)` but then you'd get a complexity message. Its a circular loop with no ending.

Comment: A calls B calls A calls B without ever matching anything.

Comment: Otherwise known as _infinite recursion_. You could change it to `(?<A>a(?&B))(?<B>b(?&A))` but it will never match `abab` because it needs to find more `ababab` to continue working.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex matches `^(ba)*$`

```
/^($|(?<B>(?:$|b(?&A)))(?<A>a(?&B))?)/
```

***Explanation***

One of the challenges with mutual recursion (next to avoid left recursion) in regexen is that there is no separation between *declaration* and *use* of a named pattern. Therefore, assuming you have `n` consecutive named patterns in your regex, you must make sure that upon exit in the `k`th named pattern, the named patterns `(k+1),...,n` do not need to match any more.

This is accomplished in the present case by marking the definitional occurrence of `A` as optional.

Further points to note:

- Breaking recursion:
  When trying to match `B`, the alternative of being at the end of the input string terminates recursion.
- Outermost alternative:
  Allows for matching the empty string

***Alternative***

Given that a particular string `xyz` will never occur in the input, a separation between declaration and use of a named pattern can be simulated.:

- Write out the definitions of all named patterns sequentially at the beginning of the regex
- Prefix that sequence with the unmatchable string
- Mark this construction as optional.
- Use the named pattern as needed afterwards

Due to `xyz` the 'declarations' will never match, however, for the remainder of the regex all names have been defined.

For `^(ba)*$`:

```
/^(xyz(?<B>(?:$|b(?&A)))(?<A>a(?&B)))?(?&B)/
```

Comment: The tip on avoiding left recursion was the way to go. I devised a way based on yours and I'll explain it in a post here